# How can I take different percentages of the value in a column and add them up to assign in a new SQL column?

Tags: sql, database

I have a column in my table named as "FundedAmount" and I want to create a new column while running my query on SQL named as "Commissions" and this newly created column needs to have the tier wise percentages summed up according to the equation as follows:

5%(0$ - $5000) + 1%($5001 - $10,000) + 0.5%($10,001 - $20,000) + 0.25%(Remaining Amount)

So, For Instance in the case of the example below the "Commissions" column would have value:

5%(0$ - $5000) + 1%($5001 - $10,000) + 0.5%($10,001 - $20,000) + 0.25%(Remaining Amount)

250 + 50 + 5.515 = 305.515

[image]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your tiering table so it looks like:

```
low    high      percent
0      5000       0.05
5000   10000      0.01
. . .
```

Note that I changed the bounds so all amount are included, including fractional amounts.

Then you can calculate this using a subquery like this:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum( (least(tt.high, t.fundedamount) - tt.low) * tt.percent )
        from tiers tt
        where t.fundedamount > tt.low
       ) as commission
from t;
```